# ServiceStack: Incorrect metadata for SOAP?

Tags: soap, servicestack

I followed the [Create your first webservice](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice) tutorial. When I go to the Hello Service Soap11 metadata page, I see the following:

```
POST /xml/reply/Hello HTTP/1.1 
Host: localhost 
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ...
</soap:Envelope>
```

The line `POST /xml/reply/Hello HTTP/1.1` seems incorrect. When I use the [Postman Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) and post to `/xml/reply/hello` to test the SOAP endpoint. It doesn't work. The response is a `400 Bad Request` with a message "Could not deserialize 'application/xml' request..."

Then I change the URL to make the request post to `/soap11` instead, it works with status code `200 OK`.

This problem happens for the Soap12 metadata page too.

Seems like something is not right with the metadata page generation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the code, this does look like a bug.

I have fixed the problem and submitted a pull request to ServiceStack, pending for acceptance.

Pull request: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/389

Update: Pull request has been merged into ServiceStack master branch. Problem solved!